# how to redirect/rewrite wordpress url on iis server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, iis, web-config

i am working on a wordpress website.In this what i want is that when a user hit my website url as `www.domainname.com/index.php` it should redirect to `www.domainname.com`.That means i just want url without index.php . I also want that when user enters `www.domainname.com/any-page-name` then it simply ends with slash just like `www.domainname.com/any-page-name/`. I have tried rewrite rules in web.config file but it not works.Any help is appriciated , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite rules in .htaccess, the link below has a tutorial about it:

http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained/